# What kind of XML document describes this DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

What kind of XML document describes this DTD ?
I cannot understand the "ref paper".

```
<!ELEMENT mag(paper *)>
<!ELEMENT paper(title ,author+,ref*)>
<!ELEMENT title #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT author #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT ref paper>
```

Answer (score 6):

The DTD you have is not syntactically correct. Here's a fixed DTD and an example of a document that parses:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mag [
<!ELEMENT mag (paper*)>
<!ELEMENT paper (title ,author+,ref*)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ref (paper)>
]>
<mag>
  <paper>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <author>Blah</author>
    <author>Blah 2</author>
    <ref><paper><title>Bar</title><author>John Doe</author></paper></ref>
  </paper>
</mag>
```

There's nothing special to the declaration of the `ref` element. That is allows `paper` means that the structure can recurse (so to speak) a `paper` can contain a `ref` that contains another `paper` which can contain a `ref`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
<!ELEMENT ref paper>
```

basically states that the element `ref` should consist of a single instance of element `paper`.

The XML fragment would be something like:

```
 ...
 <ref>
   <paper>
     ....
   </paper>
 </ref>
 ...
```